# Flickity: after drag/throw the selected cell is sometimes out of the gallery viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickity

I am working on an infinite draggable Carousel using [flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) by metafizzy.

Using the freeScroll + wrapAround Props, it works quite nice selecting the next cell on drag.

```
$('.gallery').flickity({
    freeScroll: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    prevNextButtons: false
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwpfyuzz/)

But if i do a strong 'drag' and 'throw' the cells, the selected cell sometimes animates out of the viewport.
I think the check for the selected cell occurs on mouseUp, but it would be great, if the selection-check also occurs while the animation after the throw.

Does somebody know how to achive that?
Any Resources to free-scrolling infinite Slider/Carousels are welcome too.